# Mysql join tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in the database.

The first table is the one that contains user information and which looks like:

```
    id     |     name   |     status    
---------------------------------------
    1      |    john    |      1
    2      |    helen   |      1
    3      |    mike    |      1
    4      |    tina    |      1
    5      |    jim     |      0
    6      |    nina    |      1
```

The second table contains registered users for some service:

```
   sid     |   status  
------------------------
    1      |     1
    2      |     1
```

The third table contains registered users for other service:

```
   oid     |   status  
------------------------
    3      |     1
    4      |     1
```

I should make a query that will found all users with the status '1' from the second and third table and then get name and id of all those users from the first table (with users information). That result from this example would look like:

```
   id     |     name   |     status    
---------------------------------------
    1      |    john    |      1
    2      |    helen   |      1
    3      |    mike    |      1
    4      |    tina    |      1
```

What will that query looks like? Should I use INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 2):

`INNER JOIN` is the right approach.

The query would be

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, user.status
FROM table1 AS user
INNER JOIN table2 AS service1 ON service1.sid = user.id
INNER JOIN table3 AS service2 ON service2.oid = user.id
WHERE service1.status = 1 AND service2.status = 1
```

If you want users which are on service1 OR service2, the query could be

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, user.status
FROM table1 AS user
WHERE user.id IN (SELECT sid FROM table2 WHERE status=1) OR
      user.id IN (SELECT oid FROM table3 WHERE status=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns the id, name and status of users which have a row in the second table (calling it service1) with status1, a row in the third table (service2) with status1:

INNER JOIN solution:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.status
FROM users u
JOIN service1 s ON s.sid = u.id AND s.status=1
JOIN service2 o ON o.oid = u.id AND o.status=1;
```

Sub-queries solution:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN (SELECT s.id FROM service1 s WHERE s.sid = u.id AND s.status=1)
AND u.id IN (SELECT s.id FROM service2 o WHERE o.oid = u.id AND o.status=1)
```

Sub-queries solution for users in one of the second or third table:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN (SELECT s.id FROM service1 s WHERE s.sid = u.id AND s.status=1)
OR u.id IN (SELECT s.id FROM service2 o WHERE o.oid = u.id AND o.status=1)
```

Comment: @user576875- I tried with this query but the result shows only those users who are in both tables, the second and the third table, not all users from these two tables.

Comment: added a third query which should return users who are in one of the tables

Comment: @user576875- Thanks. This works great. Is it better to use INNER JOIN or query like this one with multiple SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from firsttable 
inner join table2 on id = sid and table2.status = 1
inner join table3 on id = oid and table3.status = 1
```